# React Typescript Class Component Default Props Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, components

I created a simple class component with some props. Since Typescript 3 and above, they state that defaultProps by default will use the same Interface as the component's props itself. [reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx)

In the following code example, you can see I created a component, extending React.PureComponent with a given interface. One prop is called boolean with type boolean.

Then I got the `static defaultProps` assignment where I made an "accidental" typo where I put a string instead of a boolean.

```
import React from "react";

export interface ExampleClassProps {
  string: string;
  arrayOfStrings: { test: string };
  boolean: boolean;
}

class ExampleClass extends React.PureComponent<ExampleClassProps> {
  static defaultProps = {
    string: "asd",
    arrayOfStrings: { test: "asd" },
    boolean: "true" //this should throw an error, since I'm assigning a string to type boolean
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.string}</div>;
  }
}
export default ExampleClass;
```

From my understanding Typescript should now throw an error saying, type string is not assignable to type boolean, but it doesn't.

I'm on Typescript 3.5.3 and I installed @types/react.

Also, writing a similar component as a functional component does actually work, so I only got the problem with classes:

```
import React from "react";

export interface ExampleFCProps {
  stringProp?: string;
}

const ExampleFC: React.FC<ExampleFCProps> = ({ stringProp }) => {
  return <div>{stringProp}</div>;
};

ExampleFC.defaultProps = { stringProp: 1 }; //this throws an error, since number is not type string

export default ExampleFC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's quite what the [documentation you referenced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx) means.  It says this:

> The default-ed properties are inferred from the `defaultProps` property type.

I think this means that it looks at the `defaultProps` property and infers the type from **its value**: it doesn't look at the type of the `props` of the component. That makes sense, because if it did assume that `defaultProps` has the same type as `props` then you could never supply just a partial set of the props by default: `defaultProps` would always have to give a value for **everything** in `props`.

What the documentation suggests for such a case is this:

> Use `static defaultProps: Pick<Props, "name">;` as an explicit type
>   annotation instead, or do not add a type annotation as done in the
>   example above.

In your example, if you want to supply default values for every prop, and have a it type-checked, explicitly tell the compiler that `defaultProps` is of type `ExampleClassProps`:

```
class ExampleClass extends React.PureComponent<ExampleClassProps> {
    static defaultProps: ExampleClassProps = { // <-- explicitly state the type
        string: "asd",
        arrayOfStrings: { test: "asd" },
        boolean: "true" //this now does not compile, since you're assigning a string to type boolean
    };
```

By the way, there's an interesting tip about this here: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/10-typescript-pro-tips-patterns-with-or-without-react-5799488d6680.  See the section called "9. Use type inference for defining Component State or DefaultProps".

Comment: Hmmm seems as if I understood the documentation wrong, thank you very much!